# How to create file in some directory C++

Tags: c++

I would to create a file generated.txt into "I:\Dropbox....\generator\" folder.

```
// array with 7 elements filled with 0
int num[7] = {0};
// create text file to write into genereted numbers
ofstream generated;
generated.open("I:\\Dropbox\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\Number generator\\generated.txt", ios::app);
// seed... without that function randomed one time
srand(time(NULL));
// randomize the array values
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    num[i] = rand();
    generated << " \t" << i+1 << ": " << num[i];
}
generated << endl;
generated.close();
```

`

But if I run program on another PC that doesnt have "I:\" disk, than it doesnt work, also program worked, but it doesnt save generated numbers.
So my quastion is: how to create directory on another PC with generated.txt file? It should run program and create file there where program droped.
Thx and sorry for my english )

Comment: Drive letters only work on some operating systems. There are other issues, too, like mapping a drive onto someone's machine is a dangerous practice. Also, you cannot count on that drive letter (I:) being available, it could be a DVD drive, for example.
Better practice is to stick to relative paths inside your program's home directory, or to use a designated spot for your files, like the user's hidden AppData folders on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `argv[0]` to get string with path to your program executable.
Below one could see the example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout<<argv[0]<<std::endl;
    std::stringstream sst(argv[0]);
    //char delimeter='/'; //for Linux
    char delimeter='\\'; //for Windows
    std::string part, full="", part_prev="";
    while (std::getline(sst, part, delimeter))
    {
        full+=part_prev;
        part_prev=part+delimeter;
    }
    full+="generators.txt";
    std::cout<<full<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) does not know about directories (that might change in C++14 experimentally).

You need some operating system specific API. If your system (e.g. Linux) has it, consider POSIX (e.g. its [mkdir](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html), `chdir`, `readdir` functions).

Or use some library wrapping the OS-specific functions, e.g. [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) or [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)

BTW, you could use environment variables with [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) (or some program argument, or configuration data) and construct some file path (e.g. using `snprintf`) from them.

Notice that the very notion of directory is OS specific. And that some OSes don't always use `/` (as mandated by POSIX) as the directory separator.

<sup>BTW, I'm using Linux and a file path like `"I:\\Dropbox\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\Number generator\\generated.txt"`  behave *very differently* than on your PC. (on my system your file path does not refer to any directory, it is just a weird looking file name starting with `I:` in the current directory)</sup>

Comment: boost::filesystem can also be used if you want something more C++-like.